# Fill vector with probability calculations

Tags: matlab

I have the following vectors:

```
s = [1 0 2];
lambda = [1 2 3];
```

These vectors could be n-dimensional, not just 3-dimensional only. Based on this information, I would like to create a 'probability vector':

```
p = [poisspdf(0, lambda(1))+poisspdf(1, lambda(1)) poisspdf(0,lambda(2)) poisspdf(0,lambda(3))+poisspdf(1,lambda(3))+poisspdf(2,lambda(3))]
```

So the vector s determines how many terms there are per probability vector element, e.g. s(1)=3 means p(1) = P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2).

I tried something like this:

```
p = sum(poisspdf(0:s,lambda));
```

However this, only works for s=[0 0 0] and crashes for s=[1 0 0] and so on. (Error at poisspdf: Requires non-scalar arguments to match in size.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working with two dimensions, i.e. you calculate `p` for different `lambda`, but also integrate until you reach different `s`. With `lambda` explicitly looped over, this may look more clear to you:

```
n_p = length(lambda)
p = zeros(n_p, 1);
for k = 1 : n_p
    p(k) = sum(poisspdf(0:s(k), lambda(k)))
end
```